# Location of an image on layout?

Tags: android, parameters, location

I need to find the X coordinate of an `image` on `layout`. I tried this:

```
logo = (ImageView) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.logo); 
int [] koordinates = new int [2];
logo.getLocationOnScreen(koordinates);
firstPosition = koordinates[0];
Log.d("firstPosition", "firstPosition: " + firstPosition);
```

But it returns 0.  I tried to use the `getLeft()` method as well, but it returns 0 too.
Is there any proper way to do it? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** *Solved!* Found a way to do it...
Not onCreate, but surely after it! So it's still ok!

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
    logo = (View) tabBar.findViewById(R.id.logo);
    firstPosition = logo.getLeft();         
    Log.d("firstPosition", "firstPosition: " + firstPosition);      
}
```

Comment: You want to get ImageView position on load of Activity or on some event say click/touch event?

Comment: I want to get this position onCreate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call:

```
logo.getScrollX();
```